# PHP Simple Login Error

Tags: php, authentication

I am writing a simple PHP login script but have some problems with the mysql query.
The structure of the auth table looks like this:

```
username attribute value

userA    password  123456
userA    status    active
userB    password  987654321
userB    status    active
```

This structure looks stupid, but I have to keep the structure like this.

```
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="select username, value from authtable where (attribute <=> 'password')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$myusername = $result['username'];
$mypassword = $result['value'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

the following is the processing of the result:

```
if($count==1){

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:manager.php");
}
else {
echo "Login failed";
}
```

But this script always returns login failure, though I provide the correct username and password.

Could someone please point out where the problem is?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: OT: Never, ever save passwords in plain text!

Answer (score 0):

```
select username, value from authtable where (attribute <=> 'password')
```

Will give you as many records as you have users.

You forgot to specify which user you want.

```
SELECT `username`, `value`
FROM `authtable`
WHERE `attribute` <=> 'password'
    AND `username` = '{$myusername}'
```

Comment: Thank you, I finally found that just use $sql = "select * from authtable where username='{$myusername}' and value='{$mypassword}'" will work, as there will always be only one row matches the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

always

table like :

```
username password  status    

userA    123456    active
userA    987654321 active
```

and sql like :

```
select username, value from authtable where (password = ? and username = ?)
```